# Canon Rebel T3i autofocus has stopped working

Tags: canon-600d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why won’t my new Canon Rebel T3i take a picture with the 18-55mm lens in autofocus mode?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24910/why-wont-my-new-canon-rebel-t3i-take-a-picture-with-the-18-55mm-lens-in-autofoc)

New Canon Rebel T3i camera worked flawlessly until today, when the auto focus stopped working correctly.  When I press the shutter half way down it auto focuses past a subject, then in front of it, and then back again, but never quite on focus to the subject.  In the viewfinder the exposure warning circle blinks and won't let the shot be taken.  I have tried clearing all settings (including custom functions for good measure), trying with flash on and off, different lighting, IS on and off, and finally trying a second lenses.  I have resorted to moving the AF mode to off on the lenses and I am then able to manually focus and take pictures.  I have found several references to others having this issue, through Google searches, but never a resolution.  Thoughts?

Comment: As you've tried this with more than one lens, I'd suggest doing a factory reset of the camera; instructions on how to do this will be in the manual.